# Error 310 in Chrome when browsing to a certain web site

Tags: google-chrome

When I browse to the web site [www.jensunmack.dk](http://jensunmack.dk) using Google Chrome, I get the following error:

> Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)

I have no problems when using Firefox. I've tried to clear my cookies in Chrome but it didn't help. Is there anything else I can do, or should I get in touch with the webmaster? (I'm just an ordinary user of the site).

Comment: The text and the link don't match. Which is it?

Comment: Well, I think there's an automatic redirect from http://www.jensunmack.dk to http://www.jensunmack.dk/wordpress-2 . I have the same problem in either case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If clearing the cookies doesn't work, contact the webmaster.